# Specify the type of attributes, where type is imported

Tags: python, types, pycharm

I tried searching for this, but couldn't find an answer.

I am using `PyCharm` and I do not seem to be able to specify the type of an imported class.

```
import rospy

class A:
  """
  Attributes:
    subscriber (rospy.Subscriber): my subscriber
  """
```

First I am getting a spelling error on the `rospy` part, and I can't seem to be able to do code completion to get this type.  I did try putting the rospy.Subscriber in '', but still no go.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not really an answer, but I was able to get a little further with it.  I tried to use double CTRL-Space on Subscriber, from the above example.  It expanded out to ropy.topics.Subscriber, so it seems that import rospy does some aliasing.  Since I am new to Python I am not sure whether aliasing is the right term.

Now to see if this will give me what I needed in terms of having good type support in my code.

I did find that someone else has had this issue and it still seems to exist, code completion works well in code, but not in the docstring :(

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206600515-Type-hints-not-resolving